# Opencart Journal2 Theme header full width

Tags: html, css, header, opencart

I use Journal2 theme for opencart3, I use the second one to customize for my website.However I found it cannot change header into full width, how to modify that to make it full-width?

Answer (score 0):

at the backend,go to "journal"-"dashboard"-"setting"-"headers"-"general",
select "off" for "Boxed Header",
then it will show full-width

actually,here is for coding ,not for setting,
for setting ,the best solution is to ask the theme's seller.